# Solve $0.1t^4 – 3.2t^{3/2}$ for particle coming to instantaneous rest

Tags: integration, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I need to factorize this to find real roots of "t"!!
Question is about differentiation and integration

> Q.  A particle moves in a straight line. It starts from rest at a fixed point $O$ on the line. Its acceleration at time $t$ s after leaving $O$ is $a \,{\rm ms^{−2}}$, where $a = 0.4t^3 − 4.8t^{1/2}$!!!
>   Show that, in the subsequent motion, the acceleration of the particle when it comes to instantaneous rest is $16 \,{\rm ms^{−2}}.$

For this I need to integrate equation of acceleration and find to values of "$t$" for which the integrated equation is equal to zero.
What are values of "$t$" for which equation of velocity is equal to zero????

Comment: Please use MathJax otherwise people are bound to downvote. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is the link to a tutorial.

Comment: So you need to solve $t^{5/2}=2^5$?

Comment: "It starts from rest at a fixed point $O$...  Its acceleration at time $t$ s after leaving $O$ is $a$...."  So there is an initial condition (rest) $v=0$ at time $t=0$.  This helps you to determine velocity $v$ by integrating $a$ from time $t=0$.  Have you gotten this expression for the velocity as a function of time?  (Editing to remove inappropriate tags.)

Answer (score 1):

Integrate to get the velocity and set it zero (rest)

$$v(t^*)=\int_0^{t^*} a(t)dt= 0.1(t^*)^4-3.2(t^*)^{3/2}=0$$

which factorizes as

$$0.1(t^*)^{3/2}[(t^*)^{5/2}-32]=0$$

and has the solution $(t^*)^{5/2}=32$, or $t^*=4s$.

Thus, the acceleration of the particle at the instantaneous  rest time $t^*$ is $a(4)=16m/s^2$.